# Insert nested arrays into sql from python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, list

I have a list contains many lists in python.

```
my_list = [['city', 'state'], ['tampa', 'florida'], ['miami','florida']]
```

The nested list at index 0 contains the column headers, and rest of the nested lists contain corresponding values.  How would I insert this into sql server using pyodbc or slqalchemy?  I have been using pandas pd.to_sql and want to make this a process in pure python.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

expected output table would look like:

```
city |state
-------------
tampa|florida
miami|florida
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @jignatius sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column names are coming from your list you have to build a query string to insert the values. Column names and table names can't be parameterised with placeholders (?).

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect(my_connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

my_list = [['city', 'state'], ['tampa', 'florida'], ['miami','florida']]

columns = ','.join(my_list[0]) #String of column names
values = ','.join(['?'] * len(my_list[0])) #Placeholders for values
query = "INSERT INTO mytable({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(columns, values)

#Loop through rest of list, inserting data
for l in my_list[1:]:
    cursor.execute(query, l)
conn.commit() #save changes
```

**Update:**

If you have a large number of records to insert you can do that in one go using `executemany`. Change the code like this:

```
columns = ','.join(my_list[0]) #String of column names
values = ','.join(['?'] * len(my_list[0])) #Placeholders for values
#Bulk insert
query = "INSERT INTO mytable({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(columns, values)
cursor.executemany(query, my_list[1:])
conn.commit() #save change
```

Comment: how would I make this a batch insert?  My real data set I have hundreds of rows of values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `conn` is already open connection to your database:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
for row in my_list:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO my_table (city, state) VALUES (?, ?)', row)
cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns value are are the first elemnts in the array, just do:

```
q ="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stud_data (`{col1}` VARCHAR(250),`{col2}` VARCHAR(250); """
sql_cmd = q.format(col1 = my_list[0][0],col2 = my_list[0][1])

mcursor.execute(sql)#Create the table with columns
```

Now to add the values to the table, do:

```
for i in range(1,len(my_list)-1):
   sql = "INSERT IGNORE into test_table(city,state) VALUES (%s, %s)"
   mycursor.execute(sql,my_list[i][0],my_list[i][1])
mycursor.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "Record Inserted.")#Get count of rows after insertion
```